# Error: Statements must be seperated by newline or semicolons Pylance

Tags: python

[The line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Phu.png)
[The error, please help, i have tried researching but it is not fixing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjI3O.png)

Comment: If the command is in cmd, simply remove the `import` part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.